# iOS Today View Not Running on Device

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget

I have created my first Today View extension that just displaying some texted it retrieves from a shared NSUserDefaults. It works perfectly and is ready to be shipped based off of how it displays and works through simulator, but when I try to run it on my device nothing happens.

The widget shows up in notification center but it has no height. I run my main app from Xcode and it wont let me attach the debugger to it and none of my breakpoints, nslogs get hit.

I tried running the Today View target on device and I can't get the provisioning profiles to be accepted. I also tried attaching the process of the today view to the debugger with the full bundle ID and it never attaches no matter wether I open notification center or not.

Im very new with extensions and have searched a ton around for an answer to this but cant find anything that worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may stumble upon this all I had was add arm64 to the list of acceptable architectures and it worked

Answer (score 1):

and in my case i tested on SDK 8.2 and my test device running on 8.1.1 totally forgotten about Deployment target changing to 8.0 worked like charm..Might be helpful for the one careless like me..

Answer (score 0):

In your widget build settings set the architectures to armv7, arm64

see this post [iOs today extension do not launch - lost connection to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236333/ios-today-extension-do-not-launch-lost-connection-to-device/26238356#26238356)

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the help but see above your post